# link href to website css does not work since upgrading to Windows Server 2019

Tags: xslt, iis-10, windows-server-2019

We have a process that converts xml to html via a XSLT file.  We are using css from the same website that is using the process.

```
    <head>
        <link href="$siteURL/css/pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    </head>
```

This worked when the server was Windows Server 2012 R2, but does not work since upgrading to Windows Server 2019.

If I change the link href to the absolute path, then the css is read correctly and the html file has the correct style.

When I changed to the absolute path, everything works correctly.

Comment: Shouldn't that at least be `<link href="{$siteURL}/css/pdf.css" ...>`?, to make any sense as XSLT. Or what is the `$siteURL` supposed to be, an XSLT variable or parameter?